# Compare different statistical models that forecast the same result

Tags: forecasting, model-comparison, application, scoring-rules

**Background:**

I'm assessing the future condition of a product where we have 18,000 units in the inventory.

The product can be assessed as Poor, Fair, Good, or Excellent, based on a `condition_index` rating that we determine. For example, if for one product, the index reading is below 20, it's considered poor, 20 to 50 is fair, 50 to 70 is good, and 70+ is considered excellent

It takes eight years to go through a full cycle of condition data for all 18,000 units. With these tests, we take each product in the inventory and provide a `condition_index` manually with a reader. On the other hand, we can use deterioration curves that say, if the product is x years old then it is in y condition.

The way we're reporting at the end of the year is the following way:

```
Condition   Frequency
Poor        10% (1800)
Fair        20% (3600)
Good        30% (5400)
Excellent   40% (7200)
```

Here are how we perform the models:

**Model 1:**

- Starting at product with `ID = 1`, we measure the `condition_index` directly from the product.
- It takes 8 years to cycle through all the products as we can only test about 2,500 a year.
- At the end of the year, we average all the ratings from all years up according to the table above, and determine the `condition_index` that way.

**Model 2:**

- We use the yield curves based on the age of current products. The yield curves go from 100% to a 0 where 100% represents a product with no damage and 0 represents a product that is fully damage and unusable.
- For example, if we replace, rehab, or replace `product_id = 5` with a new one, then its age goes to 100%.
- Based on the cycle of changing and maintaining the products, we determine the condition index that we have. so based on the age of a product, we determine a condition_index and then report on the whole inventory that way.

Our previous modelers have used Model 2 as our "official" condition reporting method; citing that consistency of data is not reliable in Model 1 as well as model 2 provides for a consistent replicable methodology. I'm not sure that I fully agree as I think parts fo the data from Model 1 should be used since it is actual collected product data and even better if we can combine it with model 2.

**What are some of the ways I can compare method 1 to method 2 to determine which is the proper one to use?**

**EDIT 1**

Note that the current results show that model 1 is predicting that we have 20% in poor vs 10% in poor when using model 2

Answer (score 1):

You can use what's called a "proper" scoring rule. Generically, "scoring rule" just refers to a way of numerically evaluating the quality of a forecast of a probability. However, a "proper" scoring rule reaches its optimal value (minimum or maximum, depending on the function) when the forecasted probabilities are the true probabilities of the data being modeled.

A good introduction to the topic (besides Wikipedia) is the paper "Strictly Proper Scoring Rules, Prediction, and Estimation" by Gneiting and Raftery.

Answer (score 0):

I would run a very simple experiment, similar to the [coin bias problem](http://www4.uwsp.edu/psych/stat/9/hyptestd.htm).

However, the null hypothesis and the significance level of the test are quite subjective, they depend on the nature and the fault-tolerance of operations.

In your case, for example, a conservative null hypothesis could be: poor <= 10%